# Align tables next to each other based on 1-N relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One contains all Services with their values. And the second table would described which services is related to which.

Table 1:

```
|Service|Value|
---------------
| S1    | 1   |
| S1    | 2   |
| S2    | 4   |
| S3    | 5   |
| S4    | 6   |
| S4    | 8   |
| S4    | 7   |
| S5    | 3   |
```

Table 2: Related Services. 1-N Relationship

```
|Service|Related|
|---------------|
| S1    | S3    |
| S1    | S4    |
| S2    | S5    |
```

As a result I like to align Services and their related Services next to each other. Just like this. The values can be shown in ascending order.

```
|Service|Value(asc)|Related_Service|Value(asc)|
----------------------------------------------|
| S1    | 1        | S3            | 5        |
| S1    | 2        | S3            | null     |
| S1    | 1        | S4            | 6        |
| S1    | 2        | S4            | 7        |
| S1    | null     | S4            | 8        |
| S2    | 4        | S5            | 3        |
```

Is this possible in SQL or T-SQL?

Comment: Your desired result makes not sense. The service S3 does not have a value of `NULL`. Service S1 (2 values) is related to S4 (3 values), so this relationship alone must produce 2x3=6 records. Your ascending order of values isn't ascending. Service S1 does not have a value of `NULL`.

Comment: S1 has 2 values. S4 has 3 values. Is there a way to produce 3 rows which aligns S1 and S4 next to each other? Maybe with row_number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like what I want. Using Row_Number() helped me!

```
if object_id('tempdb..#a', 'U') is not null 
    drop table #a;

select *, row_number() over (partition by Service order by Value) Row_Num into #a from #Service

select 
    isnull(a.service, b.s) Service, 
    a.Value, 
    isnull(b.Service, a.r) Related_Service, 
    b.Value
from
(
    select a.Service, Value, Row_Num, b.Service s, b.Related r from #a a right join #Service_Related b on a.Service = b.Service 
) a
full outer join
(
    select a.Service, Value, Row_Num, b.Service s, b.Related r from #a a right join #Service_Related b on a.Service = b.Related
) b
on a.s = b.s and a.r = b.r and a.Row_Num = b.Row_Num
order by a.Service, b.Service
```

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you want. Neither (S1, NULL) nor  (S3, NULL) are records in your table, so why should they be returned in the result? And why is (S1, 1, S4, 7) not contained in your result?

Comment: I want to put S1 and S4 next to each other based on ordered Value. For instance, (S1,1) is the first record of S1 and (S4,7) is the second record of S4. So there shouldn't be a row in the result. row_number() makes it work. I concede that my wording is not perfect...

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1 a ON t2.Service = a.Service
LEFT JOIN t1 b ON t2.Related = b.Service
ORDER BY a.value, b.value;
```

Comment: I think this is close but not quite what I want. Your query generated 9 rows but it should only be 6. For instance, when S1 links with S4 there should be only 3 rows because S4 has 3 values.

Comment: Here is a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e526879693ee7f3b4e1f15452cf9266d